# Showing equivalence relation.

Tags: relations

On the set $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ define $(m,n)\sim(k,l)$ if $m+l=n+k$

1. Show that $\sim$ is equivalence relation on $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$
2. Draw a sketch of $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ that shows several equivalence classes.

My book does not even explain how to do this kind of problems. I understand that we need to show that it's symmetric, reflexive, and transitive. However, I usually do it  with a matrix. How can I put the above problem into matrix form and then draw diagrams from it?

Comment: I fail to see what this has to do with matrices at all. Could you be more specific about what you mean by "put the above problem into matrix form"?

Answer (score 1):

**addendum**:

This answer is only useful if $\mathbb Z$ (and subtraction) is allready at your disposal. It seems however that you are busy here with constructing $\mathbb Z$. If that is the case then have a look at the direct proof.

---

Note that $(m,n)\sim(k,l)\iff f(m,n)=f(k,l)$ where $f:\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb Z$ is defined by $f(m,n)=m-n$. That makes it easy to prove that it is an equivalence relation:

1) $f(m,n)=f(m,n)$ reflexive

2) $f(m,n)=f(m',n')\Rightarrow f(m,n)=f(m',n')$ symmetric

3) $f(m,n)=f(m',n')\wedge f(m',n')=f(m'',n'')\Rightarrow f(m,n)=f(m'',n'')$ transitive

In general if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a function then $\sim$ defined by $x\sim x'\iff f(x)=f(x')$ is **always** an equivalence relation on $X$.

Two (trivial) equivalence relations on any set $X$ are $\{(x,x)\mid x\in X\}$ and $X\times X$.

---

**addendum**

Here a direct proof

For convenience I start with $(m,n)\sim(k,l)\iff m+l=k+n$ (instead of $n+k$). Then:

$$m+n=m+n$$ for each pair $(m,n)$ is exactly the statement that $\sim$ is reflexive.

$$m+n=k+l\Rightarrow k+l=m+n$$ deals with symmetry.

$$m+n=k+n\wedge k+q=p+l\Rightarrow m+l+k+q=p+l+k+n\Rightarrow m+q=p+n$$ deals with transitivity.

Comment: The trouble with this approach is that the exercise is clearly part of a program to construct $\mathbb Z$ given only $\mathbb N$. So assuming that we already know $\mathbb Z$ and can use it in our proofs makes it rather pointless.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, you are right. Thank you. I will add this to my answer, and also I will add an alternative proof.

Answer (score 1):

(a)R in N will be reflexive iff (m,n) R (m,n).
Now, m+n=n+m$\implies$(m,n) R (m,n)$\implies$R is reflexive

(b)R in N will be symmetric if (m,n) R (l,k)$\implies$ (l,k) R (m,n).
Now, m+k=n+l$\implies$l+n=k+m$\implies$ (m,n) R (l,k)$\implies$ (l,k) R (m,n)$\implies$R is symmetric.

(c)R in N will be transitive if (m,n) R (l,k) and (l,k) R (p,q)$\implies$(m,n) R (p,q). Now,
(m,n) R (l,k) and (l,k) R (p,q) $\implies$ m+k=n+l and l+q=k+p$\implies$k=n+l-m and k=l+q-p
$\implies$n+l-m=l+q-p$\implies$n-m=q-p$\implies$n+p=q+m$\implies$m+q=n+p$\implies$(m,n) R (p,q). Thus, R is transitive.

Comment: In c) you are using subtraction. If $\mathbb Z$ is yet to be constructed (which is possible here), then subtraction is not defined yet.